# Metaprogamming elixir for module proxy

Tags: cache, meta-programming, elixir

I'm working on my first real Elixir application, after dabbling for a few years. In my elixir/phoenix application I have to work with data over an external REST API. For my purposes, I can tolerate some staleness in the data so I would like to cache the data from the external system and consult the cache during request handling instead of calling out to their API for every request. So I have this plan to write one module which connects to the API, and then access it through a caching proxy module, which uses [Cachex](https://hex.pm/packages/cachex) to cache return results for some small amount of time. This is the proxy module:

```
defmodule MyApp.SlowApiCache do
  alias MyApp.SlowApi
  Code.ensure_compiled(SlowApi)

  for {func, arity} <- SlowApi.__info__(:functions) do
    args = Macro.generate_arguments(arity, __MODULE__)
    def unquote(func)(unquote_splicing(args)) do
      cache_key = {unquote(func), unquote_splicing(args)}
      Cachex.fetch!(:slow_api_cache, cache_key, fn ->
        SlowApi.unquote(func)(unquote_splicing(args))
      end)
    end
  end
end
```

So it simply generates a matching function for each function in the wrapped module and when the cache misses then it passes it on to the real API module. In my code I write the data pulling functions in the `MyApp.SlowApi` module but in the rest of the program I access those functions through the `MyApp.SlowApiCache` functions instead.

Does this make sense or am I shooting myself in the foot somehow? Is this going to have issues in production? Is this kind of thing idiomatic in Elixir?